# How to remove disabled attribute of a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple textareas in my HTML form followed by an edit link for each. When I click an 
edit link, the corresponding textarea should be enabled. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".edit").click(function(){
            $(this).attr("id").removeAttr("disabled");
        });

    });  

</script>

<textarea  id="txt1"  disabled="true"></textarea>
<a class="edit" id="txt1" >edit</a>

<textarea  id="txt2"  disabled="true"></textarea>
<a class="edit" id="txt2" >edit</a>
```

Why is the textarea not being enabled when the corresponding link is clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`id`s can only be used once in a page. you can't have 2 elements (or more) having the same id.

instead, [do this](http://jsfiddle.net/BBtVv/2/):

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- group each in divs -->
    <div>
        <textarea disabled="true"></textarea>
        <a class="edit">edit</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea disabled="true"></textarea>
        <a class="edit">edit</a>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myform').on('click','.edit',function(){ 
            $(this)                       //when edit is clicked
                .siblings('textarea')     //find it's pair textarea
                .prop("disabled", false)  //and enable
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

if you can't use divs, then you can use `prev('textarea')` instead of `siblings('textarea')` to get the preceding textarea.

Comment: @Josehp, wouldn't this affect both textarea elements?

Comment: @JonasEverest that's the purpose of the `div`s (to guard siblings), but I updated my answer if `div`s aren't possible.

Comment: Note: jQuery does support multiple same `id` in one document.

Comment: @Joseph, yes it is invalid, but jQuery still supports it.

Answer (score 3):

You're re-using ID values - this is a big no-no. If you're going to give these an ID, you need to do something to differentiate the `txt1` link from the `txt1` textarea. In the code below, I've added a `_link` suffix to the links.

```
<textarea id="txt1" disabled="true"></textarea>
<a class="edit" id="txt1_link">edit</a>

<textarea id="txt2" disabled="true"></textarea>
<a class="edit" id="txt2_link">edit</a>
```

With that small change, we can now modify the disabled property of the textarea:

```
$(".edit").on("click", function(e){
  $( "#" + this.id.replace("_link", "") ).prop("disabled", false);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The selector, unfortunately, includes a use of the `replace()` method. If you remove the ambiguity in ID's between the links and the textareas, you can do away with this.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/unebur/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to remove disabled attribute of anchor tag by $(this). Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".edit").click(function(){
                $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).removeAttr("disabled");
            });

        });  

</script>

<textarea  id="txt1" class="txtedit" disabled="true"></textarea><a class="edit" rel="txt1" >edit</a>
<textarea  id="txt2" class="txtedit" disabled="true"></textarea><a class="edit" rel="txt2" >edit</a>
```

Comment: There is an extremely strong likelihood that this isn't going to work. id's are supposed to be unique, and each browser has a different, undefined behavior for how to deal with HTML pages where there is more than one instance of a specific id.

Comment: my bad. didn't realize both id are same value. we can use something else for anchor here. rel could be possible and access via .attr("rel")?

Comment: Absolutely! You could edit the HTML in your answer and show an example, if you wanted to be thorough. :)

Comment: Pretty cool! Looks like it works well. As an aside, the jsfiddle links make for great examples, but you should be sure to **edit** your actual answer and update it with the code as well. Should your link ever die, having the code in your answer ensures that it still has value to other users years from now. Thanks again for the follow up!

Answer (score 1):

Hello please make some changes as mentioned below

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.txtAreas').attr('disabled', true);

          $("#txt3").click(function () {
            $('#txt1').removeAttr("disabled");
          });

          $("#txt4").click(function () {
             $('#txt2').removeAttr("disabled");
          });

     });
 </script>

    <textarea id="txt1" class="txtAreas"></textarea><a href="#" class="edit" id="txt3">edit</a>
    <textarea id="txt2" class="txtAreas"></textarea><a href="#" class="edit" id="txt4">edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that's an onclick handler, $(this) is going to point at the element you clicked on, which is the `<a>` tag. That doesn't have a disabled. You need to move up the dom tree to the parent node, which'd be the textarea, and remove the disabled attribute there:

```
  $(this).parent().removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Hi Marc, the textarea is a sibling, not a parent. Take a closer look at his HTML. It's a bit misleading because of the way he has the HTML formatted.

Comment: @jmort: Ah yeah, phooey. Just noticed he's got duplicate IDs on the a and textarea elements too...